# Codeigniter - session userdata size

Tags: codeigniter, session, size, limit

I store my session in database with Codeigniter,
maybe stupid my question, but i do not catched if session data has a size limit, and i can't understand  what will happen in the app if reach that limit?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit when using database to save sessions. CI serializes the data using serialize and saves it to database.

Only limit then could be the field in the database, which differ in cases:

TEXT    65,535 bytes    ~64kb
MEDIUMTEXT   16,777,215 bytes   ~16MB
LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes     ~4GB

Comment: Text should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

you can store user_data in database with TEXT field size, TEXT field can store ~64kb.

Comment: but what happens when reached the TEXT limit so?

Answer (score 0):

hello guys set user_data in database with BLOB field size for fine et it 's recommanded by codeigniter documentation

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```